# Explorer.exe doesn't start automatically on Boot

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

For some reason when I boot my laptop now (winxp), it doesn't start explorer.exe automatically; I'm left with a desktop background and a mouse pointer. I have to run taskman and start explorer.exe manually.

Recently I had Spyware Dr. detect a severe threat, and I was wondering if there was anyway to re-hookup explorer.exe on startup.

Comment: It sometimes does that on my laptop too. Have no idea why but sometimes it boots ok and sometimes I have to run it myself. Maybe I'm not patient enough and it will start it but I can't wait more than 15 minutes for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click start
2. Click Run
3. Type "cmd" then hit enter
4. Type "sfc /scannow"

Note: U will need ur XP installation CD

Comment: I only have a restore CD, will this matter?

Comment: Yes because the restore CD has Recovery tools not the installation files.

Comment: @baseballboy64116 it's asking me for a Windows XP SP3 CD.  I don't have one of those.  Mine is like SP2 or SP1.  I downloaded all of those updates off the Internet.

Comment: If u hagve acess to another compuiter u will need to slipstream the SP)3 update. So please download it and use this tool to slipstream ur disk.
http://home.midmaine.com/~nlite/nlite/nLite-1.4.9.1.installer.exe

Comment: @baseballboy64116 I tried this but it was to fix a different problem (actually the fix worked on that problem! :) )  Additionally, I was required to download the Windows SP3 CD to fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Check that it hasn't been disabled to run at logon with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx):

[image]

Comment: @Matthew Lock, yeah mine looks just like yours...does the system rewrite that registry key when you run explorer.exe?

Answer (score 2):

That is a strong indication of malware on your system!
While that may not necessarily be the problem, its something to think about first.

Here is [one discussion thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3665617.php) and [another older one](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=176273).

Check

1. Can your start it manually or is the executable itself missing

   - What is registered at the Winlogin Shell key (referred in another answer here)

Comment: He mentioned that he can start it manually with Task Manager.

Comment: @musicfreak, good point, I missed that. So, we need to know whats connected to the Shell key. That would indicate past window-manager installations or malware association attempts (that seem to have failed).

Comment: @nik I'm assuming that the Shell key is in the registry?  What is the path to it and how do I check it?

Comment: @nik Oh wait @Matthew Lock has that in his answer...right?

Comment: @leeand00, `scoopdreams` has it in his answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these steps to get explorer.exe to start with logon again :

1. open up Registry Editor (regedit.exe)
2. go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS NT/CURRENT VERSION/WINLOGON
3. find the "Shell" key and replace whatever value you find down there with explorer.exe

Hope this helps!

Comment: You may wish to check all of the registry values related to system startup.  http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html

Comment: the WinLogon/Shell one is the most common attack target for malware. check that one first, then the rest as greyDrifter has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

i created a new ADMIN account. transferred my documents from old account to new one. then deleted the old admin account. everything is perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Can you create an entry in the startup list? In start, all programs, startup. Just create a new shortcut to explorer.exe (good luck tracking down the path). Works on Vista, maybe xp.

Not a solution I know, but a fairly easy workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this a few times now, the majority caused by pesky malware.

Try performing a [system restore](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084) back to when your computer was working okay.

It will simply roll back the registry and system files to a particular date.

1. Log on as **Administrator** (or a user with local administrator rights)
2. Click **Start** > **All Programs** > **Accessories** > **System Tools** > **System Restore**
3. Select **Restore my computer to an earlier time** and click **Next**
4. Select the most recent system restore point from the list and click **Next**
5. Click **OK**
6. Click **Next**

Give that a go.